# ASP.Net ListView clearing Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have got multiple dropdownlists one the page and I want to clear the data everytime it has been changed.  I called the following code in the SelectedIndexChanged of the dropdownlists.

```
private void ClearSelection()
    {

        lvApplications.Items.Clear();        
        lvApplications.DataSource = null;
        lvApplications.DataBind();        

        ltLoadedRecords.Text = "0";
        this.FilteredData = null;
    }
```

However, strange thing is happening in my list view.  The data is removed, but it still binds the data to the list view.

[image]

Please help me....

Comment: can you paste your whole code including binding so that we can get idea whats going on?

Comment: Make sure, you are not calling databind after this and it is not inside the update panel